# How to use Paths.get(args[0]) to get file in data folder in Eclipse?

Tags: java

I tried to use command lines arg to get input from test01 file in data folder, while it said Error opening file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RWA1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GImc1.jpg)

Comment: 1) Exceptions have an (usually) informative message, better have this printed too; 2) are you sure the file is found in the folder `/data` (and called `test01`); 3) read and consider [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/16320675)

Comment: You'// need to specify the full path, not realtive

Comment: I very much doubt you have a /data directory directly off the root of the file system which is what is showing as part of the path. Use the full absolute and proper path and you might get a different result

Comment: Please paste your code and error message here in the question. Leaving them in images makes it difficult to search and read

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the right path to your file.

`/data/test01` means that your file lays at `root/data/test01` for any unix-like filesystem, but for your example you have enter the relative path according to your working directory of your TokenizerTest like e.g. `data/test01` or `../data/test01`